# Jupyter Dashboard - Displaying data in weird format

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, dashboard

I have installed Jupyter dashboard, however, when I choose either Grid or Report layout, my data is displayed as below:

[image]

I have tried to uninstall and re-install but doesn't seem to work.  I am running Jupyter notebook 6.1.6 and Python 3.

Any idea what might be causing this? It is the same on all my notebooks.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Although it's not mentioned in the [docs](https://jupyter-dashboards-layout.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting-started.html) this project is [no longer developed](https://github.com/jupyter-attic/dashboards)

Answer (score 1):

That is definitely weird!!  If the notebook or your code is acting weird sometimes it is best to press the “RESET BUTTON”. Reseting the kernel clears all in memory objects and restarts your code from the very top.

```
 To reset the kernel press the reset button, which is the curved arrow button, located under the word 'Kernel'.
```

[image]